# Office Scripts in Power Automate - Sharing Scripts but not via Workbook

Tags: power-automate, office-scripts

In using Office Scripts in Power Automate, how can i share the scripts with other team members so when they run a flow, I dont have to share within a workbook.  I don't want standard users accessing the workbook and having visibility of the script.
I understand office scripts are stored in the creators onedrive.
Is there a way to securely share?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a secure way of sharing this as of yet. I did notice in the most recent Office Add-ins community call that there are more enhanced admin controls so you can allow Office Scripts to be turned on for only certain people.

[image]

You can see the YouTube video [here](https://youtu.be/hGVdftCzs20?t=1004)